# Saving a drawing done using FingerPaint.java code in android

Tags: android

I have done a sample painting app using APIDemo's FingerPaint app. Instead of the "usual" pattern of setContentView(R.layout.main) it uses a class MyView that extends View and sets content as setContentView(new MyView(this));  now whatever I draw I want to save it in the SDCard. For this I require to know the rootview using getRootView. This is got by the object of layout(for ex: LinearLayout L1 = new...) L1.getRootView. Because I am using this MyView, I am not able to get the rootview nor able to save the bitmap.

```
    myview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    myview.requestFocus();
    myview.getRootView();

    System.out.println("MYVIEW = "+myview);

    myview.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    myview.layout(0, 0, myview.getMeasuredWidth(), myview.getMeasuredHeight());

    myview.buildDrawingCache(true);
    mBitmap = myview.getDrawingCache();
    //System.out.println("myview.getDrawingCache() = "+newview.getDrawingCache());

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
    System.out.println("BITMAP = "+mBitmap);

    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "test.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to know how do I save my drawing using a menu button click?

Thank you

Comment: Can you just get the drawable from t view and use that?

Comment: no I cant @Akonsu....Ideally I should be able to getRootView using object of LinearLayout object. But in this case there is not layout so I am not getting sources to getRootView.

Comment: why not? is there a technical difficulty? are you getting an error?

Comment: How can I get the rootview using this MyView. Without that, if I am trying to save anything on the sdcard, the bitmap is returning null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of effort into research I bumped into this http://blahti.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/how-to-save-jpeg-files-in-the-android-emulator/ This solved my issue of saving the drawing.